# Loading SQL from spring properties does not run

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring

I got this sql propertie inside my spring configuration:

```
<property name="LAUSFT">
            <value>
                SET @vfrom = ?;
                SET @vto = ?;
                SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT s.*, @rank
                := @rank + 1 rank
                FROM quiz.score s, (SELECT @rank := 0) init
                ORDER BY points DESC
                ) s
                WHERE rank BETWEEN @vfrom AND @vto
                ORDER BY rank;
        </value>
        </property>
```

the sql runs without problems if I execude it in the mySQL workbench.
It is also correct wired in my Dao class. But if I execude the sql inside my dao class I got everytime this error:

```
    org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [
                SET @vfrom := ?;
                SET @vto := ?;
                SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT s.*, @rank := @rank + 1 rank 
                FROM quiz.score s, (SELECT @rank := 0) init 
                ORDER BY points DESC
                ) s
                WHERE rank BETWEEN @vfrom AND @vto 
                ORDER BY rank;
        ]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @vto := 1;
                SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT s.*, @rank := @rank + 1 rank 
                ' at line 2
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:233)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:603)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:637)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:666)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:674)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:714)
    at de.bc.qz.dao.ScoreDao.loadAllScore(ScoreDao.java:77)
    at de.bc.qz.dao.ScoreDaoTest.testLoadAllScore(ScoreDaoTest.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @vto := 1;
                SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT s.*, @rank := @rank + 1 rank 
                ' at line 2
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3536)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3468)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2107)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2648)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2086)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2237)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:644)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:587)
    ... 34 more
```

as I sad. everything works fine If I run the sql in the workbench so where is the problem?

here the java function:

```
public List<Score> loadAllScore(int pFrom, int pTo) {
    return createJdbcTemplate()
            .query(mLAUSFT,
                    new Object[] { pFrom, pTo }, mScoreMapper);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jdbc statement is one single sql instruction.

Here you try to run multiple sql instructions in one statement. You must split your sql on `;` and create an execute one statement for each instruction.

From [official doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html):

> A Statement is an interface that represents a SQL statement.

Comment: do you have a reference/tutorial for this?

Comment: @StefanBeike that's covered in JDBC tutorials.